# Azure Search how to find a substring in a text field

Tags: azure, search

I need to filter based on a partial string contained in a specific field, regardless of their tokenization.
For example, the field "file_name" contains the value "Las Vegas Brochure.pdf" and I need to retrieve this record even if I look just for "Vega". The problem is that it works just if I specify the whole word like "Vegas", as you see in the following two examples.
[image: WORKGING]

[image: DOES NOT WORK]

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using queryType=simple. Just change to queryType=full and it should work.

PS: I'm not 100% sure if filter supports Regular Expressions. I believe you must use it in the search part

e.g.

search=/.*vega.*/&queryType=full&searchModel=all

Comment: Thanks Thiago, but unfortunately I had already tried both tests, and they don't work. BTW I use the search part for searching "Las Vegas" within all fields, while I use filter to sub-filtering the results based on the file_name field which should contain a specific string. In other words, I need to identify the records which contain "Las Vegas" in any field, AND also contain "VEGA" within the file_name field.

Answer (score 0):

Another couple of examples using the search part:
[image: it works]
[image: DOENS'T WORK]

Comment: can you add a screenshot of your index definition?

Answer (score 0):

I found it: I missed this dot. Thank you very much

[image: right]